# How to query users to count all with a custom capability and limit it to a set of roles?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, wp-user-query

On a site with 12 custom user roles I need to count users with the 'supervisor' custom capability but limited to four specific roles.

The following code counts all users with the 'supervisor' capability, but does not limit it to the specific roles:

```
$args = array(
    'role'           => 'supervisor', //this is a custom capability
    'role__in' =>  array( 'level1', 'level2','level3','level4' ) //these are custom roles
    
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$supervisors = count($user_query->results);
```

Comment: There have to be two underscores: `role__in`

Comment: note that the answer to this will be different for those using WP 5.9 due to new options in `WP_User_Query` that were recently announced on the official Make WP blog. Note that roles are not the same thing as capabilities, and the `supervisor` capability is not a role, so `'role' => 'supervisor'` would not make sense

Comment: Also, before the roles and capabilities system was introduced, privileges were done using levels, you will want to check that your `level1` etc don't clash with backwards compatibility code leading to strange and odd bugs

Comment: I corrected the two underscore error and now the code looks to be working. 

I will double check the role names for clashes, but it does appear that  'role' => 'supervisor' does work for finding capabilities.